# AngularJS how to bind select value in a ng-repeat directive?

Tags: angularjs, binding

currently struggling with a thing that I thought would be easy...
I'm trying to update a value in a `ng-repeat` directive using a `select` dropdown.

Here is what the `HTML` looks like:

```html
<div ng-repeat="groupeQuestions in questionnaire.GroupesQuestions" class="umb-group-builder__group">                          
    <select ng-model="groupeQuestions.TypeQuestionId" ng-options="value.Id as value.Description for value in typesQuestions ">                             
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="groupeQuestions.TypeQuestionId"/>
    <button ng-click="saveGroupeQuestions({{groupeQuestions}})" >Sauvegarder</button>
    <button ng-click="deleteGoupeQuestions({{groupeQuestions.Id}})" >Supprimer</button>
</div>
```

And here is the js controller function used to update the item :

```js
$scope.saveGroupeQuestions = function (groupeQuestions) {
    console.log(groupeQuestions);
    surveyPluginResource.saveGroupeQuestions(groupeQuestions).then(function (response) {
        $scope.questionnaire = response.data;
        navigationService.syncTree({ tree: 'survey', path: [-1, -1], forceReload: true }).then(function (syncArgs) {
            navigationService.reloadNode(syncArgs.node);
        });
    });
};
```

Somehow, I'm missing something with the binding thing, because if I change the value in the dropdown, the textbox is updating as well.

But when it reaches the controller, the console.log() displays the item which does not contain the new `groupeQuestions.TypeQuestionId`.

I'm new to js and angularJs too, so is there something on binding that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `{{}}` interpolation when passing a scope variable to a function

```
<button ng-click="saveGroupeQuestions(groupeQuestions)" >Sauvegarder</button>
<button ng-click="deleteGoupeQuestions(groupeQuestions.Id)" >Supprimer</button>
```

Comment: Gosh, that was it ! Thanks a lot ! :)